# Get thread ID of current active window

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to obtain the thread ID of the active window. Is there a Windows API function that will let me obtain this information?

There is the `GetCurrentThreadId` function, but it returns an ID for the *calling* thread, not the active window thread, so it's not useful for this purpose.

**EDIT:**

As suggested to edit my question to provide additional information on why do I need this, here it is:

I'm implementing a [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to capture keyboard input, and since keyboard layout can vary from program to program I want to ensure the layout is obtained for active window that processes the keyboard:

code snippet:

```
HWND active_window = GetForegroundWindow();
DWORD thread_id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(active_window, nullptr);
HKL hLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id);
```

Now having the correct keyboard layout for active window I translate the key:

```
BYTE pKeyState[256];
GetKeyboardState(pKeyState)

wchar_t result;
PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT pKbd = reinterpret_cast<PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT>(lParam);
ToUnicodeEx(pKbd->vkCode, pKbd->scanCode, pKeyState, &result, 1, 2, hLayout);
```

The answer provided suits my needs, because if passing zero to `GetKeyboardLayout` function the keyboard layout will be wrong (the same) if user changes keyboard layout during program execution.
Passing active window thread id is the way to go.

Comment: Terminology is important. The "desktop window" is something altogether different from the "active window". It's not clear which one you want, since you use both terms.

Comment: @CodyGray: You're right, the original question's use of "desktop" was confusing.  So I removed it, because the poster had previously commented and clarified that they were looking for the "active window" not the "desktop window."  Somehow the comments were deleted.  I've voted to reopen, not that it matters since an answer was already accepted.

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and although John's answer *seems* to answer your question, it's very unlikely to be the solution that you want. I would ask for you to [edit] your question and clarify what you are actually trying to do (what do you want this information for?), but it may be too late for that.

Comment: Thank you for correction I updated my question, the answer by John indeed suits my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ID of the thread which *created* the active window, though of course there might be other threads somehow involved with it since its creation.

If that's what you're after, use `GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), nullptr);`